# Every power series with nonzero convergence radius is the Taylor series of the function denoting its sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

From pg. 286 of Hassani's Mathematical Methods for Students of Physics and Related Fields:

[image]

How did the author conclude that every power series with nonzero convergence radius is the Taylor series of the function denoting its sum? How can we be sure that every coefficient $c_k$ of any power series can be expressed in terms of $c_k = \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove that, in the region of absolute convergence of a power series, you can differentiate term by term and obtain a convergent power series that coincides with the derivative. So, from
$$
f(x)= c_0 + c_1(x-a) + c_2(x-a)^2 + c_3 (x-a)^3 + \cdots
$$

if you differentiate once, you conclude that
$$
f'(x) = c_1 + 2 c_2(x-a) + 3 c_3(x-a)^2 + \cdots \Rightarrow f'(a) = c_1
$$

differentiating twice,

$$
f''(x)=2c_2 + 6c_3(x-a) + \cdots \Rightarrow f''(a)=2c_2 \Rightarrow c_2 =\frac{f'(a)}{2}
$$

See the pattern?